# null-homotopic function on circles?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am not sure whether the two results are equivalent:

1. continuous function $f$ from $S^n$ (unit circle) to $X$ is null-homotopic.
2. continuous function $f$ could be continuously extended to $B^{n+1}$ (closed unit ball).
   (1) implies (2) is quite clear. But does (2) implies (1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes (2) implies (1). $B^{n+1}$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space of
$S^n\times [0,1]$ obtained by identifying $S^n\times 1$ to a point.
A map from $B^{n+1}$ to $X$ is in effect a map from $S^n\times [0,1]$
to $X$ which is constant on $S^n\times 1$, that is a homotopy from a map
from $S^n$ to a constant map, that is a nullhomotopy.

Comment: Which set is meant by $B^{n+1}$?

Comment: Since this is a standard exercise, I guess it's more or less clear that $B^{n+1}$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: $S^n$ is unit circle in $R^{n+1}$ and $B^{n+1}$ is the closed unit ball as Fimpellizier points out.

Answer (score 4):

More explicitly, suppose $\overline{f}:B^{n+1}\longrightarrow X$ is a continuous extension of $f:\mathbb{S}^n\longrightarrow X$ and define $H:\mathbb{S}^n\times[0,1]\longrightarrow X$ by $H(x,t)=\overline{f}\big((1-t)\cdot x\big)$.

Then $H$ is an homotopy between $H(x,0)=\overline{f}(x)=f(x)$, and $H(x,1)=\overline{f}(0)$, ie, a nullhomotopy.